# How to reboot my current activity,when i connect net?

Tags: android

I am developing an application and I am displaying images from URl using xml parsing.
When internet gets disconnected I pop up alert window.

Now I wan my current activity automatically reboot, when my device connect net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to internet changes.
If you just need this logic in your activity you can do something like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private IntentFilter mFilter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  mFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
  mReceiver = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}


private class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent i) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ActivityActionBar.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
      onLoseInternet();
    }
}
}
```

`onLoseInternet()` method you should do something to reset everything.
Possibilities:

**Best way I found so far**

In the `onCreate()` method I have two calls: `getWidgets()` and `populateWidgets()`.

`getWidgets()` is in charge of doing all the `findViewById` stuff and `populateWidgets()` will basically populate them with the correct info.

So when I need to reset the info I just call `populateWidgets()`.

**Hacky way**

I don't know if this will work but you can try doing:

- `finish();`
- `startActivity(new Intent(this, this.class));`

Comment: @Thanks Macarse,Can you tell elaborate answers for my question